# freeradius and openldap : vlan attribution working with radtest but not with wpa_supplicant

Tags: openldap, vlan, freeradius

Both of my services freeradius and openldap are on the same server. The schema Freeradius is loaded into openldap.

I configured the `radiusProfileDN` of a user to link to a group. In this group, I have `radiusReplyAttribute` set to give the informations of the vlan.

- When I use the command `radtest` in local (or from the remote and already authenticated client), I recieve an Access-Accept packet (radius protocol) containing the information for the vlan. A wireshark capture show the information for the vlan is in the packet.

```
  LDAP + Radius                      LDAP + Radius ----- Switch ----- Client
    <--------                              <-----------------------------
    -------->              or              ----------------------------->
   *vlan info*                                       *vlan info*
```

- When I use the tool `wpa_supplicant` (peap-gtc protocol), I authenticate with success but the client port is not added to the vlan group. A wireshark capture show the Access-Accept packet exchanged between the switch and the Radius server dont have the vlan information in it.

```
LDAP + Radius ----- Switch ----- Client
  <------------------    <----------
  ------------------>    ---------->
    *no vlan info*      wpa_supplicant
```

From the log of openldap, the same steps are made for the authentication with radtest or wpa_supplicant :

1. read access allowed for radiusReplyAttribute on 'mygroup'
2. result was in cache (radiusReplyAttribute)
3. send_search_entry exit
4. send_ldap_result & send_ldap_response

In the ldap server, I tried putting the vlan information directly in the user, or in the already made "variable" for the vlan info but I get the same result.

Do you know where my problem come from ? It seems related to wpa_supplicant using a different protocol than the radtest command and freeradius (maybe I miss a line in the configuration) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the peap-gtc protocol for authentication.

To pass the attribute information in the Access-Accept packet, I had to edit the following freeradius file : `mods-enabled/eap`.

```
peap {
    use_tunneled_reply = yes
}
```

Now the switch port get configured in the corresponding vlan.